# Custom Lua allocation function's freeing throws COMException

Tags: c#, .net, lua, pinvoke, luajit

I'm trying to use a custom allocation function to control the amount of memory used by Lua, but for some reason I get a COMException while Lua is trying to free memory, saying that an argument is invalid (HRESULT: 0x80000003), if I let a script that creates and extends strings run for a few seconds. Here's my custom allocation function:

```
private static IntPtr Alloc(IntPtr ud, IntPtr ptr, int osize, int nsize)
{
    if (nsize == 0)
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
    else
    {
        if (osize == 0)
            return Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nsize);
        else
            return Marshal.ReAllocHGlobal(ptr, (IntPtr)nsize);
    }
}
```

There's nothing special going on, I simply set that function with `lua_setallocf` and then start to create and concat strings in a loop, to cause memory changes. The same thing happens in managed C++, using realloc and free, though I don't know if those aren't actually doing the same exact thing behind the scenes.

If I use Lua's stock allocation function everything works fine. Does anyone have an idea what might be causing this?

Update:
I just discovered that this only happens using *LuaJit*, but not with the official Lua 5.1 binaries...

Comment: Is your OS 64 bit?

Comment: Or more precisely, is your LuaJIT compiled for 64 bits?

Comment: My OS is 64 bit, yes (Windows 7). Is that important? I tried both 32 and 64 bit versions of LuaJit.

Comment: LuaJIT uses 32 bit pointer values even when compiled for 64 bit, so address truncation could have been the problem, but if you tried the 32 bit executable as well, then it's probably something different.

Comment: I just wrote on the LuaJit mailing list, where I got the hint that I shouldn't use lua_setallocf, but lua_newstate instead. I actually did try that before, but only with 64 bit. lua_newstate + 32 bit works!